# How to click drop down box with python selenium full xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the drop down box shown in the picture.

I tried full XPATH.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWvxG.png)

picture explanation ->

```
난이도 == Level  \<div class="DropDownstyle__DropdownStyled-sc-1gbppxe-0 dvGGQm dropdown"\>
```

This web element is to click on the Level drop box!  I want to click dropbox please help.. Please help me!!

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

option = Options()
option.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=option)
url = 'https://school.programmers.co.kr/learn/challenges?order=recent&page=1'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best practice:** Always try to construct Relative XPath rather than Absolute XPath. Relative XPaths are more reliable than the absolute ones.

For example, change the below absolute XPath:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]
```

To relative XPath as below: This XPath will locate the first occurring `<button>` element which has attribute `@class` and value `title`

```
(//button[@class='title'])[1]
```

**Refer the below working code:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://school.programmers.co.kr/learn/challenges?order=recent&page=1')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# Click on the 난이도 dropdown
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[@class='title'])[1]"))).click()

time.sleep(20)
```

**Result:**

[image]